# Can I add .avi files to iTunes without converting them?

Tags: itunes, avi

I have the appropriate codec installed to play .avi files with QuickTime, but iTunes doesn't want me to just drag and drop .avi files into my iTunes library. Can I somehow convince iTunes that it should accept .avi files?

(I now I can convert the .avi files into MPEG4 and then drop the MPEG4 into iTunes, but I would like to avoid that step.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Although instead of converting to MPEG4, you can put them in a `.mov` container which will act as an alias and point to the original `.avi` file. Within Quicktime (which you said you already have installed), go to **File -> Save As** and select **Reference Movie**. The file generated can be dropped into iTunes.